# Wordpress using ajax post without losing the user's login session for woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, session

How do you keep user login info during ajax post calls back to the server under wordpress and jQuery?

I'm using woocommerce on my wordpress site.  I've implemented ajax post actions under jQuery that require the current user's session inside the PHP code.  I'm not willing to come up with a custom authentication solution.

As you may know, runnning $.post or $.ajax will have your php code fail on things like `if ( !is_user_logged_in() )...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Here is a simple chunk of code which reads `$_COOKIE` for the session information on the current user, and creates a ready made callback that `jQuery` will later use to maintain session context:

```
//insert somewhere inside functions.php

add_action('wp_head', 'pluginname_ajaxurl');
function pluginname_ajaxurl() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ajaxSetup()
  {
      //Return a cookie setup function inserted into the ajax call
    return function(xhr, settings) {
      <?php
      foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value )
        echo "xhr.setRequestHeader('$key', '$value');\n"
      ?>
      return true;
    };
  }
  var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
</script>
<?php
```

Now your ajax call will look like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '/', //ajaxurl, depending on your ajax hook implementation
beforeSend: ajaxSetup(),  //Pass in the cookie information into header
data: {action: 'my_action', some_data: 'info_about_things'},
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
  if (data.success)
    alert("Awesome");
  else
    alert("Maybe next time");
}
});
```

Now ajax post will maintain session and login info for the current user inside the custom php action.

Comment: Is this the solution, or should this be the edit to the question?